# XML with C# strange behaviour

Tags: c#, xml

I am new to C# and XML and I need help with following code, I have created an Element thru C# code and wanted to insert City Element in a XML file at two places and coded the following code. But C# code inserts Element only in 4th node not in 1st node, I am not able to figure it out what am I missing.Any help will be appreciated. It is working fine if I keep only one INSERTAFTER.

```
 XmlElement childElement = doc.CreateElement("City"); // Creation of <City> ....... <City>
childElement.InnerText = "Hyderabad";// Adding Value <City> Hyderabad </City>


XmlNode SelectNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("Group/user"); //where to add XPATH expression 
SelectNode.InsertAfter(childElement, SelectNode.LastChild);//selects 1st "user" node lastchild and insert after

XmlNode refNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("Group/user[4]");// Indicating 4 Node in XML file
refNode.InsertAfter(childElement, refNode.LastChild); //selects 4th  "user" node lastchild and insert after
```

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Group>
  <user>
    <Name age="39">John Hay</Name>
    <RollNo>01</RollNo>
              === <City>Hyderabad</City> ===> is missing 
  </user>
  <user>
    <Name age="11">Ramsey</Name>
    <RollNo>02 </RollNo>
  </user>
  <user>
    <Name age="16">Roshan</Name>
    <RollNo>03</RollNo>
  </user>
  <user>
    <Name age="42">Rahiman</Name>
    <RollNo>04</RollNo>
<City>Hyderabad</City>    ==>   This is fine.      
    </user>
</Group>
```

Can I reference any ELEMENT (Ex. RollNo) based on its Text.value and insert one more element ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are moving the same instance of your city-node around your xml-document. You need to instantiate another one:

```
XmlElement childElement = doc.CreateElement("City"); // Creation of <City> ....... <City>
childElement.InnerText = "Hyderabad";// Adding Value <City> Hyderabad </City>

XmlNode SelectNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("Group/user"); //where to add XPATH expression 
SelectNode.InsertAfter(childElement, SelectNode.LastChild);//selects 1st "user" node lastchild and insert after

childElement = doc.CreateElement("City"); // Creation of <City> ....... <City>
childElement.InnerText = "Hyderabad";// Adding Value <City> Hyderabad </City>

XmlNode refNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("Group/user[4]");// Indicating 4 Node in XML file
refNode.InsertAfter(childElement, refNode.LastChild); //selects 4th  "user" node lastchild and insert after
```

/Edit: Cloning your city-node might be a bit more appropriate.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.xml.xmlelement.clonenode(v=vs.110).aspx

```
XmlElement childElement = doc.CreateElement("City"); // Creation of <City> ....... <City>
childElement.InnerText = "Hyderabad";// Adding Value <City> Hyderabad </City>

XmlNode SelectNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("Group/user"); //where to add XPATH expression 
SelectNode.InsertAfter(childElement, SelectNode.LastChild);//selects 1st "user" node lastchild and insert after

XmlNode refNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("Group/user[4]");// Indicating 4 Node in XML file
refNode.InsertAfter(childElement.CloneNode(true), refNode.LastChild); //selects 4th  "user" node lastchild and insert after
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I got it  and I have realized I need another instance of City-node.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily access specific nodex using `text()` in XPath...

Take a look at this example:

```
//get roll node by it's text
var rollNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("//user/RollNo[text()='03']");
//user to whom roll is child
var parentUserNode = rollNode.ParentNode;
//add some nodex
parentUserNode.InsertAfter(childElement, parentUserNode.LastChild);
```

Comment: Thank you . The key point is we need to identify the parent parent node of element  in reference and supply it to "InsertAfter".

Answer (score 0):

This would be much easier using the LINQ to XML API rather than the old `XmlDocument` API. For example, to do this by order:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var hyderabad = new XElement("City", "Hyderabad");

doc.Descendants("user").First().Add(hyderabad);
doc.Descendants("user").Skip(3).First().Add(hyderabad);
```

Or to select by `RollNo`:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var roll4 = doc.Descendants("user").Single(x => (int) x.Element("RollNo") == 4);

roll4.Add(new XElement("City", "Hyderabad"));
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/16s5YO) for a demo.